# Updated solution to get screenshot as image file JavaScript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, converters

I need to save some html content - inside a div or the whole page - as an image file.
I have found and tested solutions, like html2canvas or the PHP 5 functions but my constraints are as following:

- I have an MVC application architecture. That means that while I can easily generate an html file - then use tools to transform it into pdf etc. - it becomes cumbersome to add all the css files that the MVC framework does on the fly while the pages are built.
- the html2canvas doesn't render some key html5 elements - video & audi controls, that I am intensively using. Otherwise it is a very good tool ...
- the PHP 5 image functions are only running on Windows.
  I've seen that the evolutions in this area are quite rapid, therefore I'd be grateful to have some lastest proven experience that you may have with this problem. Thx

Comment: you can't get a screenshot by php or javascript in depends of a browser.

Comment: I can impose the use of Chrome